# How to switch to other Linux distro and keep data?

Tags: linux

Currently, I'm using Linux Mint on my laptop. I want to know if it's possible to switch to other Linux distro and keep all of my data (Documents and Video) except the system data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, though it is very involved if your `/home` directory is on the same partition as the root. It would require removal of every directory except `/home`, and formatting with a different filesystem might (most likely) pose an issue here. Assuming the distribution's installer preserves directories on the target drive (manually installed distros such as Gentoo or Arch can), the permissions of the directory would need to match the new user ID and group ID to allow writing to the directory by the owner. There might also be conflicts with the dot-files, which would have to be removed or hand-edited, since most applications create their own, and the applications vary slightly between distros.

The easiest and most reliable way to preserve your data with very little risk of it being deleted would be to back it up to an external computer, cloud storage (Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, MEGA, etc.), or copy it to another storage device, such as a flash drive.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
I'm new to Linux, the documents are in /root/home.
And I have the defaults setting for the installation on the first time (just click next until it finished and just set the ID. I have 320gb harddisk and ext4 taken all the rest of emty space (no unused space)